# Why did Mrs. Tyson state the incorrect movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, sabrina

In the 1995 film [*Sabrina*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114319/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt), Mr. Tyson is giving a toast to celebrate the engagement of his daughter to David Larrabee.

When Mr. Tyson is finishing his toast, he jokingly quotes *The Godfather*:

> May your first child be a masculine child

Mrs. Tyson tells Linus Larrabee that the quote was from *Serpico*.  Is there some reason why she claimed that it was from the incorrect movie?  Was this some sort of joke that Mrs. Tyson didn't know what she was talking about?

Comment: My guess is it's to show that Mrs. Tyson doesn't know what she is talking about. Elizabeth makes a comment later about how her parents try to make jokes and they often unintentionally come out as innuendos that they aren't aware of.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some reason why she claimed that it was from the incorrect movie? Was this some sort of joke that Mrs. Tyson didn't know what she was talking about?

### Yes, this was meant to be funny.

*[Serpico](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070666/)* was released in 1973, just between *The Godfather (1972)* and *The Godfather: Part II (1974)*. In both *Serpico* and *The Godfather*, Al Pacino plays a major character.

Given this, it's not completely inexcusable that Mrs. Tyson confused the films with each other.

#### How is it funny though?

Perhaps the humor of it comes from the differences in the two films, with Al Pacino trying to take down crime/corruption in *Serpico*, but being apart of it in *The Godfather*. Also, "The Godfather accent" is very well known, and so, mistaking its origins for anything other than *The Godfather* could be considered funny to some.

Comment: That line wasn't spoken to Michael (Al Pacino) in *The Godfather.* It was spoken to Vito (Marlon Brando), but it was "I hope that _their_ first child be a masculine child," a reference to Vito's daughter (Michael's sister) and her new husband.

Comment: @spoko You're right..! It's been some years since I've watched the films, but I've made the appropriate edit. Thanks.